# Undefined method 'update_attribute' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Postscontroller

```
def makeprivate
       create 
       @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
       @post.update_attribute(:public,false)
       redirect_to root_path
end
```

_form.html

```
 <% form_for Post.new do !f! %>
   <%= f.text_area:context,placeholder: 'whats up?' %>
   <%= f.submit :post %>
   <%= link_to "postprivate",posts_makeprivate_path %>
 <% end %
```

>

I am developing a social networking site.For that in posts module,i would like to make the posts private and publicbased on user;s preference.When the user clicks postprivate, it enters makeprivate method and creates a post and updates public column of posts table to false which is by default true.
when i try to do this,i get the above said error.
Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Apparently, there's no such post in the database (with this id)

Comment: hi thanks for the reply,,,,but i have a doubt....iam calling update_attribute after creating the post...then it must be there right?....can u clarify this?

Comment: "then it must be there right?" - nope. This way of creating a post (by calling another controller action) is just wrong. If you're going to create a post, call `Post` methods (like `Post.create`). Also, what's in your `params`? How can they both contain post creation parameters AND post id?